# How to send shopping cart session variables to email

Tags: php, e-commerce

I have an eCommerce website where I want items in shopping cart to be sent to a mail so order can be completed. I have my shopping cart session on the checkout page and as soon as the place order button is clicked it goes to another page where php process is been executed. I don't have errors but it sends only the last item in the cart to the mail instead of the all items in the cart. Below is the code I used to bring the cart items to the checkout page

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
$product_ids = array();
if(isset($_POST['checkout'])){  
if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){
$count = count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']); 
$product_ids = array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], 'id');
if (!in_array(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id'), $product_ids)){
$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$count] = array
(       
'id' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id'),
'name' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'),
'price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price'),
'qty' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'qty'),
'img' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'img'),   
);
echo "Product Added to cart";
}else{
echo "Product Already added to cart";       
}   
}else{
$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][0] = array
(
'id' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id'),
'name' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'),
'price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price'),
'qty' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'qty'),
'img' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'img'),
);
}
}
?>
```

Below is the code to to get the each item from the session

```
  <?php
$total =0;  
foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $r):
?>

<?php
 $prodname = $r['name'];
 $prodprice = $r['price'];
 $prodqty = $r['qty'];

?>

<?php
$total = ($r['qty'] * $r['price']);
?>

<?php
endforeach;
?>


<?php
$totalall=0;
foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $r):
$totalall = $totalall +  ($r['qty'] * $r['price']);
?>

<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Here's the code that send the item to the mail

```
<?php
include('Mail.php');

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password'; 

$from = "";
$to = "";
$subject = "$subject";
$body= "
$prodname;
$prodprice;
$prodqty;
$prodtotal;
";

$headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' =>'localhost', 'auth' => true, 
'username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'port' => '25'));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body); 

if (PEAR::isError($mail)){
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
}
else {
echo("Order Completed Successfully");
}
?>
```

I don't mind changing my code, i just need this to work. Thank You

Comment: You have an `endforeach` before you are reading in the product details in the middle part of your code. Those details need to be written to an array, you would be over writing the previous details on each pass. You then need to modify your email script to build the body using the array.

Comment: Thank you, i have edited the endforeach. What i need is how to write the session data to an array

Comment: The session data is already in an array. If you want to create another just create it in the foresch loop.